# Using OpenAPI to Receive Files in Multipart Messages

Tags: python, api, yaml, openapi, connexion

I have an API I'm running on Flask/Connexion.  The API is written in OpenAPI 3 for Swagger.  I send data via multipart/form-data to the endpoint, and everything gets through *except* the uploaded file.  I'll start by sharing my OpenAPI YAML file.  For the file I referenced [this document](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#considerations-for-file-uploads) on how to specify the schema.

```
openapi: "3.0.0"

info:
  description: No one is reading this
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: Super basic API endpoint

# Paths supported by the server application
paths:
   /api/submit:
    post:
      summary: Process a new text submission asynchronously
      operationId: submit.submit
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              x-body-name: submission
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Submission'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: That's nice

components:
  schemas:
    Submission:
      type: object
      required:
        - url
        - mimeType
        - language
        - content
      properties:
        url:
          type: string
          format: uri
        mimeType:
          type: string
          description: MIME type of the file submission
        language:
          type: string
          pattern: '^[a-z]{3}$'
        content:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
            format: binary
```

The **submit.submit** operation calls the following Python code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import uuid

def get_timestamp():
    return datetime.now().strftime(("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

def submit(submission):
    print(str(submission))

    return { "timestamp": get_timestamp(), "uuid": str(uuid.uuid4()) }
```

What the Python prints is:

```
{'url': 'http://nosite.none', 'mimeType': 'text/plain', 'language': 'eng'}
```

So no 'content' is present.  But I know the data is being sent since I captured it outbound in my browser:

```
-----------------------------138508216052
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="url"

http://nosite.none
-----------------------------138508216052
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mimeType"

text/plain
-----------------------------138508216052
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="language"

eng
-----------------------------138508216052
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"; filename="nonsense.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Now is the time for
all good men to come
to the aid of their
party.
-----------------------------138508216052--
```

Is there additional debugging I should do with Connexion that will tell me if/why it isn't passing the 'content' file?

Comment: How do you send the request to your API - using Swagger UI, Postman, from code, ...?

Comment: @Helen: data is sent from JavaScript code that sends a FormData object via XMLHttpRequest.